# $J_n =\int_{0}^{ +\infty} \frac{ t^{2n-1} \exp \left( - \frac{t}{2 n^{1/k}}\right) \sqrt{\arctan t} }{ (1+t^4)^{n/2 } }\,dt$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

- $\displaystyle J_n =\int_0^{ +\infty} \frac{t^{2n-1} \exp  \left(  - \frac{t}{2 n^{1/k}} \right) \sqrt{\arctan t}}{(1+t^4)^{n/2}} \, dt$
- What is the limit of $J_n$ ?
- I found this integral in an exercise. Does it ring a bell to any of you ? Is there an alternative proof ?

---

Attempt

- $k \geq 5$
- $\displaystyle K_n(t)= \int_0^{+\infty} \exp\left( -\frac{t}{n^{1/k}}\right) \arctan t  \; dt$
- $\displaystyle I_n= \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{ x^{4n-2} }{ ( 1+x^4)^n} \, dx$
- $\displaystyle K_n \sim \dfrac{ \pi n^{\frac{1}{k} }}{2}$  [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4108084/int-0-infty-exp-left-dfractn-frac1k-right-arctan-t)
- $\displaystyle I_n \sim \Gamma(\frac54) \frac{1}{{(n-1)^{1/4} }}\leq\frac\pi{2\sqrt2}\frac{1}{{(n-1)^{1/4} }}$ [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4107233/i-n-int-0-infty-dfrac-x4n-2-1x4n)

We apply Cauchy Schwarz, $J_n^2 \leq I_n K_n \to 0$

---

Comment: Why are you interested in this particular integral $J_n$? What is the motivation behid it? You answered the question in the last line. What is the question then?

Comment: It was an exercise.  I wonder if this integral has an interest. Or  if there is an alternative solution ( besides Cauchy-Schwarz). Thats is why I post this question.

Comment: I see. Let me add that for $I_n$, the correct pre-factor is $\Gamma(5/4)$ as it was shown by Claude Leibovici. What I gave there is an asymptotic upper bound.

Comment: ok, there is indeed a difference.